# texture maps not applied to material when using BufferGeometry loaded from .obj

Tags: three.js, 3d, textures, mesh, react-three-fiber

I'm struggling to apply texture maps to a loaded object.
(.obj exported from magica voxel).
I'm using it's child-geometry for a mesh.
Loading the Object and applying any material works fine.
But the maps (normal, roughness in that case) are completely ignored.

```js
import { useLoader } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { useTexture } from '@react-three/drei'

import { OBJLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader'
import CaseObject from '../object/case.obj'

import texture from '../texture/plastic/color.jpg'
import roughnessMap from '../texture/plastic/roughness_map.jpg'
import normalMap from '../texture/plastic/normal_map.jpg'

function Case (props) {
  const object = useLoader(OBJLoader, CaseObject)
  const geometry = object.children[0].geometry

  const matProps = useTexture({
    map: texture,
    roughnessMap: roughnessMap,
    normalMap: normalMap,
  })

  return <mesh
    castShadow={true}
    receiveShadow={true}
  >
    <bufferGeometry {...geometry} />
    <meshStandardMaterial
      {...matProps}
    />
  </mesh>
}

export default Case
```

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know react-three-fiber, but it looks like you’re importing .jpg images and directly assigning them as your roughness and normal maps. Those properties are expecting a `THREE.Texture` object, not a direct image. If the result of your `import` statement is the image, make sure you convert them into a texture first with

`new THREE.Texture(normalMap)`

... but if the result of your `import` is the string with the address of the image, then you'll have to load it with `new THREE.TextureLoader().load(normalMap)`.

Comment: thank you! 
useTexture() does that internally. 
actually the exact same codes works with other geometries...

Answer (score 1):

The person above is right. Before you add a image, you have to load it by going:

`new THREE.TextureLoader().load('../texture/plastic/normal_map.jpg')`

Comment: thank you, but this is done by useTexture internally. the above does work with other geometries...